# Return list to Partial View using JSon

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a list of Categories and along with that list I want to show the number or Count of records that match the category. I have the Json in the controller. Before I just returned a list of categories with a `foreach`. But now would like to show the count also. I created an SQL View and to tie the Categories to posts and this is what is in my ViewModel

```cs
public class PostsInCategories
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the Controller, which needs cleaned up, and UrlSlug added:

```cs
public ActionResult Category()
{
    //List<CategoryViewModel> Category = new List<CategoryViewModel>();
    //Category = db.Categories.Where(k => k.IsDelete != true).OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate).ToList().Select(a => a.ToCategoryModel()).ToList();
    var model = (from c in db.PostsInCategories
                 group c by c.Name into g
                 orderby g.Count() descending
                 select new
                 {
                     Cat = g.Key,
                     CountPosts = g.Count()
                 }).ToList();

    //return PartialView(@"~/Views/Blog/Partials/Category.cshtml", Category);
    return Json(new { result = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And my view needs to have this kind of styling and converted to except the json string:

```
@model  IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.CategoryViewModel>
<ul class="list list-border angle-double-right">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <a href="/Blog/Category/@item.UrlSlug/@item.Id">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            <span>(19)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

My question is how do I present the list in the view and how do I add the UrlSlug to the string. The UrlSlug is for the category.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: As Requested - Sql View Script

```sql
SELECT        dbo.Category.Name, dbo.Post.Id, dbo.Post.UrlSlug
FROM          dbo.Category LEFT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.Post ON dbo.Category.Id = dbo.Post.CategoryId
```

UPDATE: Current script that works as I wan it too. With help from answer below.

**ViewModel**

```
public class CategoryListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public int CountPosts { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**
I had to add the PostId because my list returns all categories and counts them even though they may not have posts associated with them. **See Partial View**.
My SqlView returned Null if the category does not have posts so I corrected that to show 0 **See Sql View**.

```
public ActionResult Category()
    {
        var model = (from c in db.PostsInCategories
                     group c by c.Name into g
                     orderby g.Count() descending
                     select new CategoryListViewModel
                     {
                         Category = g.Key,
                         Id = g.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                         UrlSlug = g.FirstOrDefault().UrlSlug,
                         PostId = g.FirstOrDefault().PostId,
                         CountPosts = g.Count()

                     }).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

**PartialView**

```
<ul class="list list-border angle-double-right">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <a title="@item.Category Posts" href="/Blog/Category/@item.UrlSlug/@item.Id">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
        </a>
            <span title="Number of Posts">( @if (item.PostId != 0)
            {  @item.CountPosts }
            else
            { <text>0</text>} )</span>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

**SqlView**

```
SELECT  dbo.Category.Id, dbo.Category.Name, dbo.Category.UrlSlug, ISNULL(dbo.Post.Id, 0) AS PostId
FROM    dbo.Category LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Post ON dbo.Category.Id = dbo.Post.CategoryId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated according to Post Owner's provided View script.**

*Sorry for the previous answer. Should request more details on the DB table schema and the script(s).*

Since your script was `Category` **LEFT JOIN** `Post`, the query result potentially return `Post.Id` with `null`. Checkout the link below:

[Sample DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nsMXDdQP4NQtm1pNwnQfHk/2)

---

> DB

Would add a new column, `PostId` to DB script. This column will be used for identifying whether a `Category` contains any `Post` or not.

```sql
SELECT a.Name AS CategoryName, b.Id AS PostId, b.Name AS PostName, b.UrlSlug
FROM Category a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Post b ON a.Id = b.CategoryId;
```

---

> Model

You need to through `Category` to access `Posts`.

Pre-requisites: `CategoryViewModel` class structure should look as below:

```cs
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public string Cat { get; set; }
    public int CountPosts { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

---

> Controller

1. `CountPosts` is for checking whether `Category` has any `Post` if `PostId` is not null. *(Updated)*
2. `Posts` is for generating a set of `Post`s where `PostId` is not null. *(Updated)*
3. Order `CountPosts` by descending. *(Updated)*
4. Seems you are using Razor with `@model` binding, then you have to return `View(model)` for the controller method.

```cs
public ActionResult Category()
{
    var model = (from c in db.PostsInCategories
                 group c by c.Name into g
                 select new CategoryViewModel
                 {
                     Cat = g.Key,
                     CountPosts = g.Where(x => x.PostId != null).Count(),
                     Posts = g.Where(x => x.PostId != null)
                         .Select(x => new Post
                         {
                             Id = (int)x.PostId,
                             Name = x.PostName,
                             UrlSlug = x.UrlSlug
                         })
                         .ToList()
                 })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CountPosts)
                .ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

---

> View

The view is changed. Each `Category` will have a nested layer, `Posts`. The `Posts` will be displayed only when `item.CountPosts > 0`.

```
@model  IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.CategoryViewModel>

<ul class="list list-border angle-double-right">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cat)
            <span>(@item.CountPosts)</span>

            @if (item.CountPosts > 0)
            {
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var post in item.Posts)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Blog/Category/@post.UrlSlug/@post.Id">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Name)
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    }

                </ul>
            }

        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

---

> Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. So it did not like the First() says it can only be used at the end or something like that. So I had to use FirstOrDefault. It only produces Categories that have Posts in them. I was looking to for an entire list of categories and if there was not Posts it would just produce 0.

Comment: My apologies this was my bad. I had to chnge the Join in the SQL View. Thanks

Comment: One small issue. I changed the Join in the view but now id is null if there are no posts associated with it and it doesn't like it.

Comment: Mind to share your View script? Thanls.

Comment: Added it up top under update

Comment: Hi, sorry for late, I have updated my answer according to your script.

Comment: So I get it, I think, However I had to change a few things according to my actual tables. But I get this on the Category Action - System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'MyProject.GeneralDTO.Post' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'

Comment: Maybe use `Post` class generated by EntityFramework? Another way is materialize LINQ query first then perform groupby operation. `db.PostsInCategories.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(/* Generate Model */).OrderBy(/* Order by logic */).ToList()`.